# How to programmatically create formulas using tildes in R

Tags: r, function, lm

I'm trying to make a function out of a section of code that gets run many times. It uses different columns for different use cases. The problem stems from needing to programmatically create a formula for `lm()`

```
arima_forecast = function(data_set, data_col, dependent_col){
    # ... Other code
    regTrain = lm(data_col~dependent_col, data=training_data)
    }

  data_set = # data.frame
  data_col = 'pos_qty'
  dependent_col = 'delivery_qty'
  data_set = arima_forecast(data_set, data_col, dependent_col)
```

Running that gives me the following error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I've verified that it works properly if I use `delivery_qty~pos_qty` and could jerry-rig a `paste()` to do the formatting, but is there a better way?

Comment: `?reformulate` maybe? `reformulate(c('pos_qty', 'something', 'something2'), 'delivery_qty')`

Comment: Thanks that will work!